# How is walking of memory stack done?

Tags: memory, stack-trace, callstack

Assume this simple C code:

```c
int test(int in){
 return in;
}

int main(){
 return test(5);
}
```

Would look something like the is AS:

```
_test:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $5, %edi
    callq   _test
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Assume i'm executing code in `_test:` and it crashes midway and I like to generate a `stack trace`. How is it done?

I know that the method is called `stack walking`.
I also know that this is architecture dependent and there are multiple ways of doing it. On `x86` we could rely on the `base pointer register $rbp`. a $rbp value on the stack equals a new frame (and a new function that is being executed).

Now do we literally walk the stack itself or do we also rely on the generated instructions?

If we only walk the memory stack, how do we know what are the values we are looking at right now ? how do we know how much to read back until we hit the previously stored `base pointer`? the stack could have a combination of integers, short, character all in different sizes. Even if we hit a pointer value how do we confirm it's pointer?

I'm guessing we need to also look at the generated instructions, starting from where the `program counter` is pointing to and go up. Using this we could tell what the values on the stack resemble? am I correct?

Some more details here:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287618300458

Comment: If you think about how the stack frame is set up, each saved rbp points to the one directly above it in the chain, and it is adjacent in memory to the return address.  It's a perfect single-linked list.  You don't need anything else if you just want the trace of function calls.  If you want to see their arguments, local variables, etc, then you have to look at more stuff on the stack, but there's still no need to disassemble the instructions.

Comment: but this is what I don't get, if you are in the middle of a function, how do you know which values on the stack refer to the saved `rbp`? you could be looking at local variables of the function saved on he stack, how can you tell where the last saved rbp is?

Comment: You start with the contents of the `rbp` register itself, as of the moment of the crash.  Say it contains the address `0x43210`.  It got its value from `pushq %rbp ; movq %rsp, %rbp` so `0x43210` is the address on the stack where the previous `rbp` was pushed.  If you load a qword from address `0x43210` you definitely have the `rbp` from the previous function, not a local variable or anything else.  And now it points to the saved rbp from the call before it, and so on.

Comment: (It should be said that this scheme of frame pointers is optional on x86-64.  There is an alternate procedure for stack unwinding, based on stack offset information stored alongside the code, but it is considerably more complicated.)

Comment: `You start with the contents of the rbp register itself.`, that's what I was missing, thank you. That makes sense. to make it clear, `0x43210` is the address of the new rbp, to get previous one we should load a qword before it as  `pushq %rbp` has already modified the stack pointer correct?

Comment: `push` leaves the stack pointer pointing to the value that was just pushed.  So each saved `rbp` is precisely a pointer to the previous `rbp`.

Comment: Yes you are right, last question, how far does it get unwinded? until the address of `rbp` is within the process address space?

Comment: The startup code is supposed to call `main` (or one of its callers) with `rbp` set to zero, so the saved `rbp` in `main` will be zero.  When you see that, you know to stop.